# External styling not being applied on the img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The External styling is not being applied on the `img` tag only. Although it is being applied to the other tags in the same file.

Home.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 thumbnail" style="height: 350px;">
    <img src="Images/1000px-Htc_new_logo.svg.png">
    <p class="test" >
        this is just  for testing the css link
    </p>
</div>
```

styles.css

```css
img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
}
p{
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

The `p` tag is working absolutely fine

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean, maybe bootstrap.css is overriding your styles.css?

Comment: Try switching the order of the bootstrap.min.css and styles.css link elements

Comment: Bootstrap might be overriding some of your styles. Try using `!important` after your styles to see if it's an overriding issue or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your vendor css (bootstrap etc) before your custom css file(s) so you can override the default vendor styles when needed.

Comment: now there seems to be another problem that the height is not being set but other properties are working fine.

Comment: Try using Firebug or console to see where the overriding styles are located. It might be a cascading issue (element over id, id over class etc.)

Answer (score 0):

several options you can try,

1) change another image to have a try. but not use this one 1000px-Htc_new_logo.svg.png

2) since you loaded several css files, you can use Firebug to take a look if there is some css rule be override.

3) you can use css with “!important” added to your style.css just for a test, to see if the external stying can be applied on the img tag. please note !important is not a good practice, just use it for debug.

```
img{
height: 300px !important;  /* just use important for debug  */
width: 100% !important; /* just use important for debug  */
border: solid 1px !important;  /* just use important for debug  */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try and avoid using !important it's not the best practice. It will override code everywhere. Instead be more specific, here what I mean by that add a class to those images and then change the class properties. Such as

```
img .imageStyling {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```